# export qplot output to pdf in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code I used:

```
library(ggplot2)
pdf('testplot.pdf')
qplot(1:10, 2:11, geom=c('point', 'line'))
dev.off()
```

If i type these into an R session, everything is fine, but if I save these lines to a file `test.R`, and then source it, the pdf file would be empty. Very puzzling.

Comment: `print(.)` is your friend  ;)

Comment: It's also in the R-FAQ.